# Get the id value from url and parse it into def

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm facing an issue in a web application. In more details, i used Flask, Python and AJAX.

*What i want to do?*

I would like to get an id from HTML using jQuery, send it to python script through AJAX and using python script delete it.

*My implementation :*

**HTML, jQuery, AJAX**

```
        function Remove() {
        $('#clientTable tr').click(function() {
            var customerId = $(this).find("td.id").html();
            console.log(customerId);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/general/delete/',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {id : customerId},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Correct')
                }
                , error: function() {
                    console.log('Error')
                }
        })

        })
    };
```

My script code:

```
@app.route('/general/delete/<int:id>')
@login_required
def delete_general(id):
    transaction.query.get(id).query.delete()
    return True
```

Using the above code i'm getting this error:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/general/delete/?id=1 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL your Ajax is using does not match the route you have defined. Your route is in the format /general/delete/1, but you are going to /general/delete?id=1.

Also note you should never do destructive operations like delete on a GET request; always use POST for these.

Comment: you have absolutely right. My mistake was that i though /general/delete/?id=1 was my route. So i change my code into 
`$.ajax({
                    url: '/general/delete/'+customerId,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id : customerId},` 
Now it works perfectly. Many thanks!